# Section numbering is X.X.0 instead of X.X

Tags: sectioning, numbering

All my section are numbered X.Y.0 instead of X.Y., e.g. 2.1.0 instead of 2.0.
The subsection start then at number 2.1.1.
In the index the sections are correctly numbered as X.Y.

Where is this configured?
I cannot find anything or I am searching with the wrong terms.

Comment: it most likely means that in some code that you have not shown `\thesection` has been incorrectly defined to use `\thesubsection` which is 0 because there are no subsections, but if you want someone to say what is wrong with the code it helps if you show the code. make a small but complete  document that shows the problem.

Comment: ... called minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!